# I'm trying to create a paging system.This is not the complete code. Getting "path doesn't exist " when running the code

Tags: loops, powershell, path

I'm new to powershell, any idea on why i'm getting the error?

Yesterday_Date = (get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyMMdd")

```
 $jsb={
  $file = 'C:\Users\d1\Documents\Batch\path\$Yesterday_Date1\page.log'
  Get-Content $file -Wait | ForEach-Object -Begin {
   $counter = 1
  $lines = @(Get-Content $file).Count
   } -Process {
        if ($counter++ -gt $lines) {
    write-host $_ 
   }
  }
    }
```

Start-Job $jsb -name Dum

```
do{
Receive-Job -Name Dum | out-file C:\Users\path\pager.txt -append
}while(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some syntax errors.

1st: missing `$` from variable Yesterday_Date. In addition, you are referring later to variable `$Yesterday_Date1`, not to `$Yesterday_Date`. Always use `Set-PSDebug -Strict` to catch such errors. Correct form is

```
$Yesterday_Date = (get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyMMdd")
```

2nd: single quote doesn't evaluate variables in strings. Double quotes do. Consider:

```
$file = 'C:\Users\d1\Documents\Batch\path\$Yesterday_Date\page.log'
$file
# Output
C:\Users\d1\Documents\Batch\path\$Yesterday_Date1page.log

$file2 = "C:\Users\d1\Documents\Batch\path\$Yesterday_Date1\page.log"
$file2 
# Output
C:\Users\d1\Documents\Batch\path\20130520\page.log
```

**Edit:**

To address the question in the comment, the problem is that jobs need special parameter processing. Use `-Arg` to pass the date variable as parameter. Like so,

```
$Yesterday_Date = (get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyMMdd") 
$jsb={
  param($date) 
  $file = "C:\Users\d1\Documents\Batch\path\$date\page.log" 
  write-host $file
}

Start-Job $jsb -name Dummy -arg $Yesterday_Date
Wait-Job -name Dummy
Receive-Job -Name Dummy
# Output
C:\Users\d1\Documents\Batch\path\20130521\page.log
```

Comment: Modified Code:
$Yesterday_Date = (get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyMMdd")
      
     $jsb={
          $file = "C:\Users\d1\Documents\Batch\path\$Yesterday_Date1\page.log"
      Get-Content $file -Wait | ForEach-Object -Begin {
       $counter = 1
      $lines = @(Get-Content $file).Count
       } -Process {
            if ($counter++ -gt $lines) {
        write-host $_ 
       }
      }
        }
Start-Job $jsb -name Dummy 
 
 Receive-Job -Name Dummy | out-file C:\Users\path\pager.txt -append

Comment: But, the above code throws up error.Error:Cannot find path 'C:\Users\d1\Documents\Batch\path\$Yesterday_Date1\page.log' because it does not exist. Note: Test-path $file True
The variable $Yesterday_Date is not getting recognized inside the script code of $jsb.The path is correct since I tried Test-Path and it gave true. What's wrong now???